# Background image fix height via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one page template structure. With the following

```
<body>
<div class=bg></div>
<header>
...
</header>
<content>
...
</content>
<footer>
..
</footer>
```

My content div have a li class and when click a li, get left 1600px.

I want, fullscreen my bg class on my site. But i don't know how can i do via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this instead, it need to be in the body if you want bg on whole page:

```
<body class="bg">
```